# How to find the number of instances of current script running in bash?

Tags: bash, grep, ps, subshell

I have the below code to find out the number of instances of current script running that is running with same arg1. But looks like the script creates a subshell and executes this command which also shows up in output. What would be the better approach to find the number of instances of running script ?

```
$cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

num_inst=`ps -ef | grep $0 | grep $1 | wc -l`
echo $num_inst
$ps aux | grep test.sh | grep arg1 | grep -v grep | wc -l
0
$./test.sh arg1 arg2
3
$
```

I am looking for a solution that matches all running instance of ./test.sh arg1 arg2 not the one with ./test.sh arg10 arg20

Comment: This might help: `pgrep -f test.sh | wc -l` and `man pgrep`

Comment: No this didnt help either, still getting the output as 3

Comment: Did you use in my suggestion `test.sh` or  `$0`?

Comment: Please add output of `ps aux | grep test.sh` to your question (no comment here).

Comment: Hi, I think $0 worked and the command that worked is "pgrep -fc $0" worked...thanks

Comment: Actually I am looking for a way to findout the script that is running with same argument...I have updated the question with that information and pgrep might not work in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this creates a subshell is that there's a pipeline inside the command substitution. If you run `ps -ef` alone in a command substitution, and then separately process the output from that, you can avoid this problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

all_processes=$(ps -ef)
num_inst=$(echo "$all_processes" | grep "$0" | grep -c "$1")
echo "$num_inst"
```

I also did a bit of cleanup on the script: double-quote all variable references to avoid weird parsing, used `$()` instead of backticks, and replaced `grep ... | wc -l` with `grep -c`.

You might also replace the `echo "$all_processes" | ...` with `... <<<"$all_processes"` and maybe the two `grep`s with a single `grep -c "$0 $1"`:

```
...
num_inst=$(grep -c "$0 $1" <<<"$all_processes")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ps -ef | grep $0 | wc -l
```

No need to store the value in a variable, the result is printed to standard out anyway.

Now why do you get 3?

When you run a command within back ticks (fyi you should use syntax `num_inst=$( COMMAND )` and not back ticks), it creates a new sub-shell to run COMMAND, then assigns the stdout text to the variable.  So if you remove the use of `$()`, you will get your expected value of 2.

To convince yourself of that, remove the `| wc -l`, you will see that `num_inst` has 3 processes, not 2.  The third one exists only for the execution of COMMAND.

Comment: Hi Nic, thanks for your suggestion, actually i need to store it to variable so that I can compare the number of instances running and take action based on that...is it possible to read the output to variable directly without creating a subshell